# API Method 9 Compiles in API Method 3 Android Project, Runtime Error

Tags: android, libgdx

I recently completed my first Android game. Made in Eclipse, the android properties have the target platform for Android 1.5 only (API level 3).

In my code, I called:

```
LinkedList<String> x = new LinkedList<String>();
// ...
x.pop(); // error
```

I can compile my code and run it on the desktop version of my project. The android project also compiles; but when I deploy it to my phone, DDMS shows me a runtime error to the effect of `no such method pop exists.`

This is because `pop` was introduced in API level 9, from what I can understand.

But my project targets API level 3. How did this code actually compile? Why did this end up as a runtime error instead of a compile-time error?

What other dark surprises are lurking in wait for me? This means I have to test every possible scenario in my game to find other errors like this; I thought this is what the compiler does -- find compile-time errors.

How did this become a runtime error? How can I find similar errors at compile time instead of at runtime?

Comment: Are you sure that you use API 3 as the target rather than minimum?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. To check this I: right-click the project, click Properties, click on Android, and under Project Build Target I have only "Android 1.5" (API level 3) checked off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some libGDX projects don't have the actual game code inside the Android project. That's why an API call doesn't trigger the failure. If that's your situation, you need to move the code into the actual android project, not just link it to the non-android project.

Answer (score 1):

You must have set the project's build target in 'Android properties' to at least API level 9 for it to compile successfully. Maybe your manifest just has a 
 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />` line in it, which I've always interpreted as meaning 'well it should be OK to run on this but no guarantees". Set your build target to level 3 in the build path and you should get an error marker.

Comment: See my comment above, it's set to 3.